# Storing arrays of data in a time-series database

Tags: array, time-series-database

I'm building an low utilization time-series database to capture yearly data points for a set of items fewer than 100,000.

My question has to do with storing arrays of data in a way that is easily queried later.

Right now the `yearly_visits` table looks something like:

```
visitID       MEDIUMINT primary key
userID        SMALLINT id of individual submitting yearly data
weight        SMALLINT weight of individual
```

The intake form also contains a checkbox with a list of favorite colors (via numeric value) from a lookup table.  Users can select one or more colors.

Should colors be stored in a separate `visit_colors` table that looks something like:

```
 visitID MEDIUMINT 
 colorID SMALLINT
```

Or is there a better way of storing arrays of data in a time series?  I haven't written any code yet, so I want to design this in a way that doesn't bite me down the road when I'm asked to query against the color data down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I've read about (but not implemented) [Timescale](https://blog.timescale.com/), a time-series database over Postgres. It claims to support all the PostreSQL native datatypes, including arrays. In that product the array type is supported within the query language. I don't imagine Postres disappearing any time soon so a solution based on it would be somewhat future-proof.